# resized images jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with my Jquery code. I'm trying to make a gallery. I want that when a person clicks on a image, to attach that image to a div and display it in the center of the screen. My problem is with images that are larger than the current screen size. I resize the image to match the screen size, but when I fade it in into the div it lags. I can't figure out why is that, and I'm sure it's not just because the image is big, if I don't resize it and let is go off the screen it fades in just fine.
The HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Gallery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Gallery.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="gallery">
    <div class="images">
        <ul class="resize">
            <li><img src="img/img1.jpg" alt="image1"></li>
            <li><img src="img/img2.jpg" alt="image2"></li>
            <li><img src="img/img3.jpg" alt="image3"></li>
            <li><img src="img/img4.jpg" alt="image4"></li>
            <li><img src="img/img5.jpg" alt="image5"></li>
            <li><img src="img/img6.jpg" alt="image6"></li>
            <li><img src="img/img7.jpg" alt="image7"></li>
            <li><img src="img/img8.jpg" alt="image8"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="backgroundOpacity"></div>
    <div class="imageBox">
        <img class="displayImage" src="" alt="displayImage">
        <img class="loadingGif" src="img/loading.gif" alt="loadgindGif">
        <img class="closeImage" src="img/closeImage.png" alt="close">
        <p class="imageNumber">1</p>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Gallery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var content = $('.gallery'),
        gallery = new Gallery(content);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The CSS :

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
/*-------------------------gallery-----------------------*/
.gallery{
    width: 1300px;
    margin: 100px auto 0;
};
/*------------------------------------------------*/
/*-------------------------images-----------------------*/
.images{
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
}
.images li{
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.resize img{
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
}
/*------------------------------------------------*/
/*-------------------------imageBox-----------------------*/
.imageBox{
    background-color: white;
    clear: both;
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: visible;
}
.backgroundOpacity{
    background-color: black;
    width: 5000px;
    height: 5000px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 0.7;
    display: none;
}
.loadingGif{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}
.displayImage{
    display: none;
}
.closeImage{
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    right: -10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.imageNumber{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    opacity: 0.6;
}
/*------------------------------------------------
```

*/

and the Java :

```
function Gallery (galleryDiv, resizeDuration, fadeInDuration) {
    this.config = {
        resizeDuration: 1000,
        fadeInDuration: 500
    };

    this.galleryDiv = galleryDiv;

    this.imagesUl = this.galleryDiv.find('.images ul');
    this.images = this.imagesUl.find('img');
    this.backgroundOpacity = this.galleryDiv.find('.backgroundOpacity'); // the background div which when is clicked hides the imageBox
    this.imageBox = this.galleryDiv.find('.imageBox'); // where the images will be displayed when they'r clicked
    this.closeButton = this.imageBox.find('.closeImage'); // top-right x
    this.loadingGif = this.imageBox.find('.loadingGif'); // the animated gif that gives the effect of 'loading'
    this.imageNumber = this.imageBox.find('.imageNumber'); // bottom-left text
    this.displayImage = this.imageBox.find('.displayImage'); // image to be displayed


    this.imagesWidth = new Array(); // the images default widths
    this.imagesHeight = new Array(); // the images default heights
    this.imagesLength = this.images.length // number of images
    this.imageBoxSize = new Array(); // [0] is width, [1] is height
    this.loadingGifSize = new Array() // [0] is width, [1] is height

    this.resizeDuration = resizeDuration || this.config.resizeDuration; // duration to resize imageBox
    this.fadeInDuration = fadeInDuration || this.config.fadeInDuration; // duration for image to fadeIn

    this.init();
};

Gallery.prototype.init = function () { // puts things into move
    this.getImageSize();
    this.bind();
};

Gallery.prototype.bind = function () { // bind events 
    var self = this;
    this.images.on('click', function () {
        var index = $(self.images).index( $(this) );
        self.showImage(index);
    });

    $(window).on('resize', function () { // center the imagebox whenever the window is resized
        self.centerImageBox(self.imageBoxSize[0], self.imageBoxSize[1]);
    });

    $(this.closeButton).on('click', function () { // hide the image
        // self.hideImage();
        self.displayImage.hide();
        self.displayImage.fadeIn(500);
    });

    $(this.backgroundOpacity).on('click', function () {
        self.hideImage();
    });
    return this;
};

Gallery.prototype.getImageSize = function () { // get the default images sizes
    var self = this;

    this.imagesUl.removeClass('resize');
    $.each(this.images, function (index, value) {
        self.imagesWidth[index] = value.width;
        self.imagesHeight[index] = value.height;
    });
    this.imagesUl.addClass('resize');

    this.imageBox.show();
    this.loadingGifSize = [this.loadingGif.width(), this.loadingGif.height()];
    this.imageBox.hide();

    return this;
};

Gallery.prototype.showImage = function (index) { // shows the image when it is clicked
    var self = this,
        imageWidth = this.imagesWidth[index], imageHeight = this.imagesHeight[index],
        imageSrc = $(this.images[index]).attr('src'),
        windowWidth = $(window).width(), windowHeight = $(window).height(),
        ratio = imageWidth / imageHeight, margin = 100, // margin - the distance from the image borders to the window borders (if image is to big)
        imageBoxHeight, imageBoxWidth;
    // resize the image to the current monitor size
    while(imageWidth > (windowWidth - margin) || imageHeight > (windowHeight-margin)){
        if(imageWidth > windowWidth){
            imageWidth = windowWidth - margin;
            imageHeight = imageWidth / ratio;
        }
        else{
            imageHeight = windowHeight - margin;
            imageWidth = imageHeight * ratio;
        }
    }
    //show imageBox and resize it
    this.imageBoxSize = [imageWidth, imageHeight]; // captures the current imageBox size
    this.imageNumber.text('Image ' + (index+1) + ' of ' + this.imagesLength) // set bottom-left text
    this.displayImage.attr('src', imageSrc).css({
        'width': imageWidth,
        'height': imageHeight
    });

    this.backgroundOpacity.show();
    this.imageBox.show();
    this.loadingGif.show();

    this.imageBox.animate({
        'width': imageWidth,
        'height': imageHeight
    },{
        duration: self.resizeDuration,
        step: function () {
            // center the image box with every resize;
            imageBoxWidth = self.imageBox.width();
            imageBoxHeight = self.imageBox.height();
            self.centerImageBox(imageBoxWidth, imageBoxHeight);
            // center the loadingGif
            self.loadingGif.css({
                'right': (imageBoxWidth - self.loadingGifSize[0])/2,
                'top': (imageBoxHeight - self.loadingGifSize[1])/2
            });
        },
        complete: function () {
            self.closeButton.show();
            self.imageNumber.show();
            self.loadingGif.hide();
            self.displayImage.fadeIn(500);
        }
    });


    return this;
};

Gallery.prototype.hideImage = function () { // hide the image
    this.imageBox.hide();
    this.backgroundOpacity.hide();
    this.closeButton.hide();
    this.imageNumber.hide();
    this.displayImage.hide();

    return this;
};

Gallery.prototype.centerImageBox = function (width, height) {
    var windowWidth = $(window).width(),
        windowHeight = $(window).height();

    this.imageBox.css({
        'right': (windowWidth - width)/2, 
        'top': (windowHeight - height)/2
    });

    return this;
};
```

Try with a big image, bigger than 2000x2000

Comment: I suggest preloading the images. jQuery is unable to get the size of the image to make any modifications because the images are not initially displayed (display: none;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the fact that the images are too big. Animations with jQuery are in fact pretty slow in performance. I would recommend that you use imagemagick on your server to create small images in the size of whatever you want the gallery to be wide. Afterwards the animations will run smoothly.